# Abstract class error. reason: actual and formal arguments differ in length

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am a beginner in Java programming, I have a test tomorrow, but still do not understand abstract classes, because each one gives me endless errors, I've read books and searched the internet, but I'm feeling very disappointed with myself.

Well, here is my latest exercice: is supposed to give the congratulations on the anniversary!

this is the abstract base class

```
abstract class Pessoa
{
    private int dia, mes, ano;

    Pessoa (int dia, int mes, int ano)
    {
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia){ this.dia = dia;}

    public void setMes(int mes){ this.mes = mes;}

    public void setAno(int ano){ this.ano = ano;}

    public int getDia(){return dia;}

    public int getMes(){ return mes;}

    public int getAno(){ return ano;}

    abstract int aniversario();
}
```

and this one is the derived class that inherits the methods

```
import java.util.Date;

class Cliente extends Pessoa 
{

    int aniversario()
       {
       int d = data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       int m = data.get(Calendar.MONTH);

       if ( d== dia && m == mes)
            return "Parabéns pelo seu aniversário! ";
    }
}
```

and the error is:

```
constructor Pessoa in class Pessoa cannot be applied to given types;
required: java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,int,int,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

the operator that you use cannot be used for the
type of value you are using it for. You are either
using the wrong type here, or the wrong operator.
```

perhaps obvious, but I can not see!
(please, sorry the bad english)

Comment: Your `Pessoa` class has a 3 argument constructor, you haven't invoked it in the `Cliente` class. Review how inheritance works.

Comment: also check your `aniversario()` method returns a `String` instead of int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a default constructor in `Pessoa` that takes no arguments.  Every subclass implicitly calls the default constructor (with no arguments) if you don't explicitly call one.    But there isn't such an explicit call in `Cliente`, and Java can't call the default superclass constructor if there isn't one.

Add a constructor in `Cliente` that explicitly calls the superclass constructor in `Pessoa`.

```
public Cliente(int dia, int mes, int ano)
{
    super(dia, mes, ano);
}
```

This problem is occurring with the constructors of the classes; it had nothing to do with `Pessoa` being `abstract`.

Comment: So if the superclass has a default constructor, I always have to call it in my subclass? and all the arguments of the superclass, or just the ones I need?

Comment: No.  If the superclass has a zero-argument constructor (default or otherwise), then you can rely on Java inserting an implicit call to the default constructor in your subclass constructor (default or otherwise).  If the superclass has no zero-argument constructor, then any subclass's constructor must be explicit so it can explicitly call a superclass constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly call constructor of the super class

```
class Cliente extends Pessoa 
{
    Cliente(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
      super(dia, mes, ano);
    }

    int aniversario()
       {
       int d = data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       int m = data.get(Calendar.MONTH);

       if ( d== dia && m == mes)
            return "Parabéns pelo seu aniversário! ";
    }
}
```